# New Programmer, How do you use If and Elif and Else statements? Its giving me NameError: name 'No' is not defined

Tags: python, if-statement, input

```
answer = input('Hi! Would you like to say something? (No or Yes)')

if answer == No or no:

    print('Okay then, have a good day!')

elif answer == Yes or yes:

    answertwo = input('What would you like to say?')

    print(answertwo, 'Hmmmmmm, Intresting.')
```

```
 **if answer == No or no:
NameError: name 'No' is not defined**
```

Comment: `answer == "No"`. There are quotes!

Comment: `No` is a variable reference, not a string value. Use `"No"` if you expected it to test the value of `answer` against a string. Also, `or` doesn't work the way you think it does.

Comment: See [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15112149); you want to test `if answer in ('No', 'no'):`. Or lowercase the string value first and then test against just `'no'`: `if answer.lower() == 'no':`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you using `.lower()` for every input. This ensures that if some types "nO" or "YeS" it takes the lowercase equivalent. Example:

```
ui = input("Type \"Hi\"").lower()
```

Next, you should really add an `else` option to your code. This is for answers you don't want them to type. This should be held in a `while loop` Example:

```
while(True):
    ui = input("Type \"Hi\"").title()
    if(ui == "Hi"):
        print("Hello")
        break
    else:
        print("That isn't a choice!")
```